# windows task scheduler: if the task is already running - not working as expected?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I have my.bat

```
@echo off
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -y -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame out.mp4 %*
pause
```

I created task to run it every hour. In the 'Settings' tab I pointed

> if the task is already running, the the following rule applies:   Do
>   not start a new instance

Into 'Selected Items' I clicked 'Run' and the task started. When task was running I clicked 'Run' again and new window with task opened. Two instance was running.

How to prevent second instance running when the first instance already exists?

Comment: *Do not start a new instance* affects on scheduled starts only, and do not affect on manual starting by any way. Also this batch started manually must not prevent scheduled start.

Comment: @Akina  Thanks a lot! It works!